# Destructuring data in state from external file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to receive all city name's from an external .js file to compare them later with the input value. The problem is when I destructure like `const { city } = this.state.cities;` and `console.log`, it return `undefined`.

```
const cities = [
  {
    key: 1,
    city: "Cambridge"
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    city: "Durango"
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    city: "Atlanta"
  },
  {
    key: 4,
    city: "Sacramento"
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    city: "San Francisco"
  }
];

export default cities;
```

and JSX file

```
class Filters extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cities: cities,
    categories: categories,
    types: types,
    salaries: salary
  };
```

How do I can get to cities without setting a specific index of object?

Comment: What do you mean by "index of object"? What does your `import` statement looks like?

Comment: I don't think you know how destructuring works yet. Take a look at: https://dev.to/sarah_chima/destructuring-assignment---arrays-16f
Or just look up javascript array destructuring

Comment: Did you `import cities from '../pathToCites/citiesFile';` in your Filters file? Also, `cities` is an array, so destructuring is a *little* different than say, an object. Arrays destructure by index, i.e. `const [a, b] = [1, 2, 3] // a = 1, b = 2`, while objects destructure by property, i.e. `const {a, b} = { a: 1, c: 2 } // a = 1, b = undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to get an object by array index, you can get it by key or city like:

```
cities.find(e => e.key === 1)
```

or

```
cities.find(e => e.city === 'city')
```